# Template Haskell: Is there a function (or special syntax) that parses a String and returns Q Exp?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I am trying to learn a bit of Template Haskell and Quasi Quotation, and I am looking for a function that takes a `String` and parses it to `Q Exp`, so the type is:

```
String -> Q Exp
```

Tried searching hoogle, but the results I saw had to do with lifting String literals to `Q Exp`, and the closest I found was `Language.Haskell.TH.dyn` which does quite what I want, but only for a single variable.

Are there other options? E.g. a special syntax? I'm just in the process of familiarizing myself with `[||]` and `$()`, so maybe there is something for this purpose too?

An example of how I imagine it would work:

```
runQ (parse "(1+)") == InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 1))) (VarE GHC.Num.+) Nothing
```

Also, I am aware of this

```
runQ [| (1+) |] == InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 1))) (VarE GHC.Num.+) Nothing
```

but this wont work with variable strings because -- understandably -- the string inside is taken as a literal.

```
runQ [| "(1+)" |] == LitE (StringL "(1+)")
```

**Edit (2015-07-25):** I've started using `haskell-src-meta`, and it seems to work well so far. However it does take quite a bit of time to `cabal install` (about 10 minutes on my machine). Which is a shame, my package is actually rather small, and I would like if install could be quick. Anyone knows of a solution that has smaller dependencies?

Comment: I believe [haskell-src-meta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta) provides this

Comment: @luqui I am a little confused by that package. It writes something is "not 100% complete yet" in the description. Shouldn't this functionality be already present within GHC? It must be, because it takes `[|(1+)|]` and is perfectly capable to turn that into `(InfixE _)`. So why is there a need for a third party package that may or may not parse correctly? Or am I misinterpreting and that is the canonical code GHC uses too? Or GHC just doesn't expose this function at all perhaps? I would be grateful for some clarity around this. :)

Comment: AFAIU GHC does not expose this code, but I am no TH expert

Comment: @luqui if that is the case, wouldn't it be much more elegant to expose it under -- say, for instance `Language.Haskell.TH.Parser.parse :: String -> Q Exp`?

Comment: It would be *way* more elegant if GHC exposed it, but it can't have that type.  It needs a type that includes all of the possible options that can affect parsing.  When it gets there, you end up having circular dependency issues between the `ghc` and `template-haskell` packages.

Comment: Hmm. But isn't it strange that there are third party, *duplicate* solutions to a functionality that is built right in to GHC? When you say circular dependencies, do you mean that it would be impossible or prohibitively difficult to expose this one single function? Also, thanks for your point about the parsing-modifier options. Fair point. A record or list passed in would be sufficient for that, right?

Comment: If this `parse` function existed, what would it's type be?

Comment: I asked almost this exact question a while ago, and it seems that no, TH doesn't have this obviously useful functionality. Which just seems weird to me...

Comment: @luqui I've started using `haskell-src-meta`, and it seems to work well so far. Want to add it as an answer so I can accept it for now?

Comment: You _can_ create such a function, since the Q Monad has a means of running IO actions, so you could pass the information via some global or thread-local state.  But it would be very un-ideomatic.

Comment: As for me, I still don't get how the template would be spliced. I thought splices can be performed during compilation only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As everyone has already said [`haskell-src-meta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta/docs/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse.html) provides

```
parsePat :: String -> Either String Pat
parseExp :: String -> Either String Exp
parseType :: String -> Either String Type
parseDecs :: String -> Either String [Dec]
```

where `Pat`, `Exp`, `Type`, and `Dec` are the same as from [`Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html).

---

> Why doesn't GHC expose its own parser?

It does. Fire up GHCi with `ghci -package ghc` (`ghc` is a hidden package by default) and you can import the [`Parser`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/Parser.html). It has functions to parse `String` into preliminary ASTs (whose data declarations are in [`HsSyn`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/HsSyn.html)) for patterns, expressions, types, and declarations.

> OK, then why does there not exist a library that uses this parser and converts its output to be the AST from `template-haskell` (the one in [`Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html))?

Looking inside [`HsSyn`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/HsSyn.html), its obvious that the AST isn't quite the same as the one in [`Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html). Open up both [`HsExpr`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/HsExpr.html#t:HsExpr) and [`Exp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Exp) and side by side you'll see that the latter is filled with types like `PostTc id <some-other-type>` and `PostRn id <some-other-type>`. As the AST is passed from the parser to the renamer to the type checker, these bits and pieces are all slowly filled in. For example, we don't even know the fixities of operators until we get to type-checking!

In order to make the functions we want, we would need to run much more than just the parser (at least the renamer and type checker too, maybe more). Imagine that: every time you want to parse even a small expression like `"1 + 2"` you'll still have to type check a bunch of imports. Even then, converting back to the [`Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html) wouldn't be a walk in the park: GHC has a variety of peculiarities like its own special global way of storing names and identifiers.

> Hmmm... but what does GHC do with quasi-quotes?

That's the cool part! Unlike `Exp`, `HsExpr` has [`HsSplice`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/HsExpr.html#t:HsSplice) for representing splices. Look at the types for the first two constructors:

```
HsTypedSplice :: id -> LHsExpr id -> HsSplice id.   -- things like [|| 1 + 2 ||]
HsUntypedSplice :: id -> LHsExpr id -> HsSplice id  -- things like [| 1 + 2 |]
```

Notice that they aren't storing `String`, they are storing an AST already! Splices get parsed at the same time as the rest of the AST. And just like the rest of the AST, the splices will get passed along to the renamer, type checker, etc. where missing information will be filled in.

> So is it fundamentally impossible to use GHC's parser

Probably not. But extricating it from the rest of GHC may be quite difficult. If to use GHC's parser we have to also run the type-checker and the renamer, it may be more elegant and simple to just use a standalone parser like `haskell-src-exts` (which is what `Haskell-src-meta` depends on) that is able to do everything in one pass (fixities, for example, are one of the things you have to give *ahead of time* to this parser).

Comment: Why would fixity not be known till type checking? Isn't that conceptually a layer over the parser to produce a more complete AST? Why would fancy stuff happen before that?

Comment: @dfeuer Fixities are filled in during the renaming phase (which occurs right before type checking), so type-checking is the first phase where fixities are fully present. I'm probably not understanding your question...

Comment: I thought the renamer was tied up with the type checker; maybe that was wrong.

Comment: @dfeuer No you understood correctly - the renamer and the type checker do feed back into each other, but only when dealing with top-level splices. The point remains that fixities for a particular block aren't even known until the end of renaming (and consequently the AST related to infix operators [may need to be rearranged](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/src/RnTypes.html#mkOpAppRn)).

Comment: I'm stumped with the exact same problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674757/how-to-splice-in-literal-strings-of-haskell-code-via-template-haskell How does TH work? Is the AST converted to literal source code, which is then fed into the "regular GHC", or does GHC use the AST directly? If it's the former, then isn't haskell-src-meta a fairly inefficient solution where the same code is being parsed twice -- once by haskell-src-meta and once by actual GHC?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda The AST inside the splice is parsed by GHC at the same time as the AST outside the splice. Critically, this all happens at compile time. You can _never_ feed run-time strings into quasi quotes (or GHC), but you can feed run-time strings to `haskell-src-meta`.