# How to call the quasiquoter for haskell syntax explicitly?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm building an eDSL on top of HaTeX. The problem I'm facing is that I want to display Haskell expressions in my LaTeX document and I want to use the same Haskell expression to help generate the document.

The obvious answer is to copy and paste the expression so that it appears both quoted and live. I want to avoid that because the expression is subject to change.

What I'm imagining is a quasi quoter that both splices its content as it stands and output a string that represents it.

For example, here is what I would like to type in:

```
document = do
    title "this is an example document"
    paragraph "This is normal text. We will now show the Haskell code that generates a table"
    [quoted| makeTable ["heading1","heading2"] ["cell1","cell2"] |]
```

and I would like the quasi quote to expand to:

```
document = do
    title "this is an example document"
    paragraph "This is normal text. We will now show the Haskell code that generates a table"
    makeTable ["heading1","heading2"] ["cell1","cell2"]
    listing Haskell "makeTable [\"heading1\",\"heading2\"] [\"cell1\",\"cell2\"]"
```

For this, I need to write a QuasiQuoter:

```
quoted :: QuasiQuoter
quoted = QuasiQuoter
     { quoteExp = \str -> [e| $(_ str) >> listing Haskell $(lift str) |] }
```

I am unsure what to replace the hole with in `$(_ str)`. I need to replace it with the Haskell expression quasi quoter but I am unsure how to call it. If `e` was `e :: QuasiQuoter` I could fill the hole with `$(quoteExp e str)` but it unfortunately doesn't work. What should I fill it with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: there is no easy way. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31412444/3072788) <s>is still</s> *was* unanswered for a reason. `String -> Q Exp` for Haskell is tough. The best way is probably through [`haskell-src-meta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta-0.7.0) which provides parsers which return Template Haskell AST. In particular the [`Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse`](http://support.hfm.io/1.2/api/haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.13/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse.html) module gives us `parseExp :: String -> Either String Exp`.

```
import Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse (parseExp)

quoted :: QuasiQuoter
quoted = QuasiQuoter
     { quoteExp = \str ->
         case parseExp str of
           Left msg -> fail "Could not parse expression."
           Right exp -> [e| $(pure exp) >> listing Haskell $(liftString str) |] }
```

Comment: That's cool, thank you! It seems to work remarkably well. I assumed because parseExp is not in the Q monad that it might not handle scopes well but it does. The package information is not specific about what is lacking. Do you know more about that?

Comment: @simon1505475 Yeah, that package is in need of some love. Under the hood it relies on `haskell-src-exts`, which gives you the ability to specify a `ParseMode`. `haskell-src-meta` probably uses [`defaultParseMode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.19.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Parser.html#v:defaultParseMode) in which case "The default is an unknown filename, no extensions (i.e. Haskell 98), don't ignore LANGUAGE pragmas, do ignore LINE pragmas, and be aware of fixities from the Prelude."

Comment: @simon1505475 I take back my previous comment. [This is the parse mode used](https://github.com/bmillwood/haskell-src-meta/blob/master/src/Language/Haskell/Meta/Parse.hs#L70-L79)