# Is it possible to emit raw source code with Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Say I have a `String` (or `Text` or whatever) containing valid Haskell code. Is there a way to convert it into a `[Dec]` with Template Haskell?

I'm pretty sure the AST doesn't directly go to GHC so there's going to be a printing and then a parsing stage anyways.

This would be great to have since it would allow different "backends" for TH. For example you could use the AST from `haskell-src-exts` which supports more Haskell syntax than TH does.

Comment: Why do you think the AST doesn't directly go to GHC? That would honestly surprise me.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question. I assumed you were looking for `-ddump-splices`

Comment: @jberryman I agree. Please suggest a better one.

Comment: "Parsing haskell code strings in a template haskell splice"? I may not be sure all what you're asking though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the AST doesn't directly go to GHC so there's going to be a printing and then a parsing stage anyways.

Why would you think that? That isn’t the case, the TH AST is converted to GHC’s internal AST directly; it never gets converted back to text at any point in that process. (If it did, that would be pretty strange.)

Still, it would be somewhat nice if Template Haskell exposed a way to parse Haskell source to expressions, types, and declarations, basically exposing the parsers behind various `e`, `t`, and `d` quoters that are built in to Template Haskell. Unfortunately, it does not, and I don’t believe there are currently any plans to change that.

Currently, you need to go through `haskell-src-exts` instead. This is somewhat less than ideal, since there *are* differences between `haskell-src-exts`’s parser and GHCs, but it’s as good as you’re currently going to get. To lessen the pain, there is [a package called `haskell-src-meta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta) that bridges `haskell-src-exts` and `template-haskell`.

For your use case, you can use the `parseDecs` function from [`Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta-0.7.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse.html), which has the type `String -> Either String [Dec]`, which is what you’re looking for.

Comment: Hmm, this is almost good enough but it still doesn't help with stuff like TH inexplicably not supporting visible type applications while `haskell-src-exts` does. Not to mention comments/docs.

Comment: Regarding [why Template Haskell doesn't expose a parser for the quoters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40985623/3072788).

Comment: @Alec So presumably [the proposal for native metaprogramming](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/NativeMetaprogramming) would make that a lot easier?

Comment: @AlexisKing I think that proposal is largely _motivated_ by this very problem, so yes: it would make this a lot easier. Thanks for the link!